# Dynamically serve index.html via a Firebase function that is invoked client side

Tags: firebase, cors, polymer, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am trying to serve my index.html after adding some open graphs to it via a Firebase function. I have seen a [solution](https://medium.com/@jalalio/dynamic-og-tags-in-your-statically-firebase-hosted-polymer-app-476f18428b8b) suggesting to invoke the function via rewrites in firebase.json which avoids dealing with CORS. But I need to call the function client side on-demand, when I send my response like:

```
res.status(200).send(updatedIndexHTML);
```

If I try to send a different HTML page it works fine. But the index.html seems to result in error "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". How can I use CORS to solve this?

It seems to me that error occurs when I try to send the response back. If I use redirect to a URL for instance, all works fine.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });


//for test, just trying to read index.html and serve it back as resposne
exports.handler = function(req, res, _auth) {

    cors(req, res, () => {

        let indexHTML = fs.readFileSync('./hosting/index.html').toString();

        //for test, just trying to serve the index.html back
        res.status(200).send(indexHTML);

    });
}
```

Comment: One thing to note is that Firebase Hosting will always serve exact-match static content before rewrites. So if you're deploying the `hosting` directory and visiting `/` it will serve the static version of `/index.html` instead of calling your function.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh, that's a great clue! Now, the question is how can I access the index.html via function and read it to update it while going around this behavior? The tutorial link I provided suggests that it works. Also, I really need to trigger my function client side so I don't want to add a rewrite rule in firebase.json as the tutorial suggests. Thanks